# Using arduino c++ library for RaspberryPi2

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, nfc, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I am doing a school project and is using visual studio Arduino Wiring Application template to develop an NFC application for RaspberryPi2 running on Windows10IOT.

The NFC reader I'm provided is the Grove NFC from seeedstudio (http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_NFC). I will be connecting the Grove NFC directly to my RPi2 using I2C and is trying to get the sample codes provided to work using Arduino Wiring Application in Visual Studio so that it can be used on the RPi2. I am trying to figure out how to import the 2 libraries provided to my project.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Any effort to solve the problem?

Comment: @manetsus still trying to solve..